# Regex - I need to replace all digits but specific 3 digits numbers

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace all digits on a log with "X", But i want to keep the HTTP status codes for info.

I've been trying different approaches. None of them worked.

```java
str.replaceAll("(?!5\d\d|4\d\d)\d{3}", "X") //Didn't worked

// Error trying to POST to /shipments/X5X5X/select?caller.id=XX592: 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
```

I need it to be:

From:

```
Error trying to POST to /shipments/28056415973/select?caller.id=116089592: 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
```

To:

```
Error trying to POST to /shipments/XXXX/select?caller.id=XXXX: 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the numbers you want to select are never followed by a space and an uppercase char A-Z you could use a negative lookahead:

```
\b[0-9]+\b(?! [A-Z])
```

**Explanation**

- `\b[0-9]+\b` Match 1+ digits between word boundaries
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not

  - `[A-Z]` Match a space and uppercase char A-Z
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TJlABR/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/VrKPGf)